# Image slider not appearing correctly in eBay

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery, thumbnails

For: http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585&ssPageName=STRK:MESE:IT#ht_520wt_1398

When a thumbnail is clicked the new image appears below by 10-20 pixels. It works fine on private host but on eBay has this issue. Any fix or help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you want help, you'll have to post your code and stop replacing the content of the entire question while people are answering it.

Comment: It also looks like you are editing the code within the auction.  How do you expect people to troubleshoot this while you're constantly changing it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your code.  All the thumbail images are missing.

The console gives a 404 errors on them...

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) adventures_thumb.jpg
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) stephens_thumb.jpg
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) residential_thumb.jpg
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) autism_thumb.jpg
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) spiritual_thumb.jpg

You are also getting a bunch of similar errors.  It appears like you are using relative paths within your script so it's looking for these things within a directory on eBay.  I assume you are hosting these components yourself so you need to use full, absolute paths including the `http://yourServer.com/yourPath/` on **everything**, all of your referenced assets.

<s>(As a side-note, AFAIK, I thought eBay did not allow any scripts within their auction listings.)</s>

---

**EDIT:**

**Since posting my answer, the link to [the auction listing referenced in the question](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585&ssPageName=STRK%3aMESE%3aIT#ht_520wt_1212) has been changed.  It's [now a whole different thing](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585&ssPageName=STRK%3aMESE%3aIT#ht_1856wt_1212), different content, different code, etc., rendering my comments above obsolete.**

To the OP:  This is a very bad practice, not only is this question and answer now useless to future readers, you've totally wasted my time.

It appears that the OP was edited while I was typing my original answer, therefore, there is no history of the original question.  [This is the auction as presented when I first answered](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585&ssPageName=STRK%3aMESE%3aIT#ht_520wt_1212).

---

**EDIT 2:**

As per [eBay's HTML & JavaScript policy](http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-javascript.html)

> **You can’t use** HTML or JavaScript that: **Calls remote scripts** and pages
>   automatically, **such as JavaScript "includes"** or "iframes."